# Error:No such property: manifestPlaceholders for class: com.android.build.gradle.managed.ProductFlavor

Tags: android, gradle-experimental, onesignal

I use `'gradle-experimental:0.4.0'` and I want to use onesignal sdk for my project. when I try to build the project with the code which have been mentioned in the example here I get this error:

> Error:No such property: manifestPlaceholders for class:
>   com.android.build.gradle.managed.ProductFlavor.

Code in Sample

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        manifestPlaceholders = [manifestApplicationId: "${applicationId}",
                                onesignal_app_id: "bbbbbb-324f-34fd-bed1-df8f05be55ba",
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "11111111"]
    }
 }
```

Code in my project

```
model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        buildToolsVersion = "23.0.2"
           defaultConfig.with {  
               applicationId = "com.myproject.company"   
                 manifestPlaceholders = [manifestApplicationId: "${applicationId}",
                                    onesignal_app_id: "234jfi4-2342-4a23-234-24235436546",
                                    onesignal_google_project_number: "111111111"]


            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 16
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
            versionCode = 3    
        }
```

Internet search revealed nothing. What should I do to remove this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked through the source code of gradle-experimental and I see a TODO on manifestPlaceholders on the latest commit so it looks like it isn't support yet.
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/6e2ee9ad8a0aeff3231f9937e46cc663aa2a64c5/build-system/gradle-experimental/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/managed/ProductFlavor.java#97

If you must use gradle-experimental instead of the normal release you will need to use the jar version of OneSignal and add the AndroidManifest.xml entries manually. See [step 2](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/installing-the-onesignal-android-sdk#2-androidmanifestxml) in OneSignal's Eclipse setup for instructions the manifest entries.

Thanks.