# how to use adobe creative sdk in NDK based project

Tags: android, android-ndk, adobecreativesdk

Hello everyone i need help in implementation for adobe creative sdk.

Note : my project is NDK based project(only lame library is used).

whenever im trying to sync Gradle then error comes.

> Error:No such property: manifestPlaceholders for class:
>   com.android.build.gradle.managed.ProductFlavor

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.8.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        /* 1) Add the Gradle Retrolambda Plugin */
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.3.0-beta4'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

        /* 2) Add mavenCentral */
        mavenCentral()

        /* 3) Add the Creative SDK Maven repo URL */
        maven {
            url 'https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/'
        }

        maven {
            url 'http://maven.localytics.com/public'
        }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

---------------------------------Module APP based----------------------------------

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

/* 1) Apply the Gradle Retrolambda Plugin */
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 25
        buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = "com.user.creativeimages"
            vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel =  16
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel =  25
            versionCode = 1
            versionName = "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles.add(file("proguard-rules.pro"))
            }
        }



    }

    /* 2) Compile for Java 1.8 or greater */
    android.compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    /* 3) Exclude duplicate licenses */
    android.packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        pickFirst 'AndroidManifest.xml'
    }



    android.defaultConfig {
        // ...
        manifestPlaceholders = [appPackageName: "${applicationId}"]
    }

    android.dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
    }

    /* 2) Compile for Java 1.8 or greater */
    android.compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    /* 3) Exclude duplicate licenses */
    android.packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        pickFirst 'AndroidManifest.xml'
    }

}
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs '../androidlame/build/outputs/aar'
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/drummer-aidan/maven" }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.17'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar:library:1.1.7'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.baoyz.swipemenulistview:library:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.0.0'
    compile 'com.afollestad:material-camera:0.4.4'
    compile 'id.zelory:compressor:1.0.4'

    /* 4) Add the CSDK framework dependencies (Make sure these version numbers are correct) */
    compile 'com.adobe.creativesdk.foundation:auth:0.9.1186'
    compile 'com.adobe.creativesdk:image:4.8.3'
    compile 'com.localytics.android:library:3.8.0'

    compile project(':androidlame')
    compile files('libs/okhttp-1.6.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar')
    compile files('libs/common-lang3.jar')
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: possible duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35167483/errorno-such-property-manifestplaceholders-for-class-com-android-build-gradle

Comment: possible duplicate............................?

Comment: Yes, the problem is not adobe creative but "gradle-experimental" , you can find more info in above link.

Comment: if you have any idea then please provide here

Answer (score 0):

Into gradle-experimental is not present "getManifestPlaceholders" method. You should change into yout build.gradle the line `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.8.3'` with `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'`
In other words don't use gradle-experimental version because the method is missing
You can see into gradle surce class. [gradle](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/6e2ee9ad8a0aeff3231f9937e46cc663aa2a64c5/build-system/gradle-experimental/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/managed/ProductFlavor.java#97)

Comment: i can't  replace  it because 'classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.8.3' is used for ndk  if i change then ndk support will not working.

did you have any alternative without replacing it..?

Comment: @vikasdube so you need 0.8.3 version?

Comment: @vikasdube try with this "com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.8.3"

Comment: no no ur going wrong  i don't need "com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.8.3" it's old verson .

i need gradle-experimental:0.8.3  because it's used for ndk support that is not supported with normal gradle